# How do I print the red, green and blue value of one of the pixels

Tags: javascript

How do I go on about changing the output image from yellow to green. I get yellow using the following code, and am wondering what needs to be changed in the green or red values in order to get the desired effect.

Here's the faulty code that's supposed to turn a red box (200 pixels by 200) green instead of yellow:

```
for (var pixel of image.values()) {
    if (pixel.getRed() > 250) {
         pixel.setGreen(255);
}
}
```

Comment: I guess that depends on the API of whatever you are using. What is `image`? What is `pixel`?

Comment: You are using `pixel of image.values()` but `of` is not a real JavaScript keyword. You want to say `pixel in image.values()`.

Comment: @Comptonburger: Welcome to ES2015! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: I stand corrected. Not a fan though.

Comment: You probably want to `setRed(0)` too. Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. The problem seems to be with RGB color space rather than code.

If the eye sees red, green, blue the brain perceives red, green, blue. No problem. If the eye sees red + green, the brain perceives yellow.

All you need to do is set the red to zero when you set green to 255:

```
     {
pixel.setGreen(255);
pixel.setRed(0);
}
```